# disable specific options for select when text box value is between certain values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a `select` box with values from the database for `service_type`. I have a `text box` for `word_count`.

When i enter a certain value in the `word count` textbox I want the select box to unpopulate/populate with the correct services. When word count is too high or too low the specific service is unavailable.

So an example is when `word_count` is `1201` the option that doesn't exceed `1200` becomes disabled for the services.

My first thought is to find the options of the `service select` by id. However Im populating my `select` from the database.

[image]

Here is some js/html code as an attempt to get these `select-options` disabled.

The `#agreement_selected_service` is the `id` for the `select`

```js
// word count

$(function() {
  $("#word-count").keyup(function() {
    var word_count = $(this).val();
    var service = $('#agreement_selected_service')
    if (word_count <= 1200) {
      // disable specific service options

    } else if (word_count <= 2400 && word_count >= 1201) {
      // disable specific service options
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-xs-7 ">
  <div class="form-group" style="">
    <label>Pricing Plan</label>

    <%= f.select :selected_service, ServiceType.all.order("id asc").collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :style => "width:100%;"%>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-5">
  <div class="form-group" style="">
    <label>How many words?"</label>
    <%= f.text_field :char_amount, class: "form-control", id: 'word-count', style: 'width:120px;', placeholder: "Ex. 500" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

All in all, I want the `options`, of my `select` with `id=agreement_selected_service`, to be disabled based on `word-count`

Comment: Can you please fix the errors in your snippet and repost your question

Comment: im unaware of any errors. can you explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the first snippet showed up something now. Before it wasnt showing anything and the second snippet is giving a jquery error - "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",

Comment: this is the ouput from your first snippet -- Pricing Plan <%= f.select :selected_service, ServiceType.all.order("id asc").collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :style => "width:100%;"%>
How many words?" <%= f.text_field :char_amount, class: "form-control", id: 'word-count', style: 'width:120px;', placeholder: "Ex. 500" %>

Comment: the second one seems to not know what `$` jquery is.. on my side on my site these work. i changed `$` to `jQuery` still the same error on this site.

Comment: And in order to make them work together, you need to add one snippet for both the html and jquery

Comment: okay i think i got it all together with no errors now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable `options` depending on its `value` attribute:

```js
let word_count = 1203,
    options = $('#agreement_selected_service option'),
    select = $('#agreement_selected_service')

if (word_count <= 1200) {
  options.each(function() {
    let tr = $(this)
    if (tr.val() <= 1200) tr.hide()
  });
} else if (word_count <= 2400 && word_count >= 1201) {
  options.each(function() {
    let tr = $(this)
    if (tr.val() <= 2400 && tr.val() >= 1201) tr.hide()
  });
}

select.change(function() {
  console.log($(this).val())  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="agreement_selected_service">

  <option value="100">Select a number of words</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1500">1500</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="2500">2500</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This works now, however the selection is still showing in the select box. is there a way to completely remove the `tr` option? so that its not seen at all and when changing word count the select box will change to the first result that is not disabled.

Comment: Do you mean to hide the `tr` element?, if so you can use `tr.hide()` instead `tr.attr('disabled', true)`.

Comment: yes that is it!! the only thing now is the currently selected `attr` isnt changing to the next one when its disabled/hidden.

Comment: Try setting `disabled` to `false` whenever you show it again.

Comment: For instance on my "picture above" when i change `how many words` to 2000, the pricing plan stays the same eventhough it is hidden on the list.